# Read Webstorage Form Data with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

In an effort to learn more about HTML5 webstorage and Javascript, I'm trying to create a simple page with a form that just has a "first name" and a "last name" field and a submit button. What I want to happen is lets say I enter "John" and "Smith" and hit enter, it will then redirect the user to a result page that has two read-only fields with the "John" displayed in the first name field and "Smith" displayed in the last name field. I'm not sure how to pull the stored information into the read-only fields. Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

Code is below:

**webstorage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Web Storage</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="nameform" action="result.html">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id= "firstname" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
<br><br>
<input onclick="store()" formmethod="post" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function store() {
    var inputFirstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var inputLastName = document.getElementById("lastname");
    localStorage.setItem("firstname", inputFirstName.value);
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", inputLastName.value);
}

</body>
</html>
```

**result.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" readonly>
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" readonly>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: have you tried using `.getItem`?

Comment: How would I use .getItem on the result.html page?

Comment: `localStorage.getItem(...)`.

Comment: So you mean something like this? `document.getElementById("firstname").innerHTML = localStorage.setItem("firstname", inputFirstName.value);`

Answer (score 0):

Index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Web Storage</title>
</head>
<body>

<form id="nameform" action ="result.html">
First name:<br>
<input type="text" id= "firstname" name="firstname">
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" id="lastname" name="lastname">
<br><br>

<input onclick="store()" formmethod="post" type="submit" value="Submit"> 
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">

function store() {

    var inputFirstName = document.getElementById("firstname");
    var inputLastName = document.getElementById("lastname");
    localStorage.setItem("firstname", JSON.stringify(inputFirstName.value));
    localStorage.setItem("lastname", JSON.stringify(inputLastName.value));
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

result.html

```
   <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Result</title>
</head>
<body>

<form>
First name:<br>
<input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" readonly>
<br>
Last name:<br>
<input type="text" name="lastname" id= "lastname" readonly>


</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

var retrivedFirstName = localStorage.getItem('firstname');
var retrivedLastName = localStorage.getItem('lastname');

document.getElementById('firstname').value = JSON.parse(retrivedFirstName);

document.getElementById('lastname').value = JSON.parse(retrivedLastName);

</script>
</html>
```

Comment: you want `.value` - these are html inputs.

Comment: I tried adding this script to my result.html page but when I click submit on the webstorage.html page, the next page still has empty fields.

Comment: Also check if it is storing to your Local Storage ?

Comment: No matter what I change, it still doesn't seem to do what I need it to do.

Comment: Hi Ben I have tried the above edited solution and had it working. The main gotcha with Web Storage is that although the specification used to say† that any object type can be stored, in fact all browsers currently coerce to strings. That means if you want to store a JavaScript object (or an array perhaps), you’ll need to use JSON to encode and decode: http://html5doctor.com/storing-data-the-simple-html5-way-and-a-few-tricks-you-might-not-have-known/